# Nginx load balancer with multiple domains

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, server-side

hopefully you could help me.

**Our setup**

Client requests a website -> Route53 -> Webserver

**Where is our platform located**

We run on GCP compute engine.

**Our goal**

We want to place an nginx server (which acts as a load balancer) in front of a web server so that this nginx load balancer will protect the web server from bad traffic.

**Web server Configuration**

Our web server has multiple domains (around 500)
It runs nginx, apache, mysql, php-fpm, bind etc'.
Everything on webserver runs fine.

**The flow we expect**

Client requests a website -> Route53 -> GCP HTTP/S or Network load balancer -> Nginx load balancer -> web server

**What we did**

We created an nginx server in GCP (centos7 + nginx 1.19)

We created a Network Load balancer (in GCP) for port 443.

We created a HTTP/S Load balancer (in GCP) for port 80.

We created health checks for both GCP load balancers.

**Configs**

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```html
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 124998;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;
    open_file_cache max=400000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;
}
```

a demo website config

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

```html
server {
        listen 80 proxy_protocol;
        server_name example.com;
        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.156.0.9:80;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}


server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 proxy_protocol;
        server_name example.com;
        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://10.156.0.9:443;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        }
}
```

GCP Load balancers configs are 100% correct and work with other of our projects.

**The problem**

Websites are working fine when accessing https://example.com. But when you type http://example.com, it fails with error 502:

```html
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

GCP Health check for HTTP/S load balancer fails because for some reason the nginx server doesn't respond anything on port 80.

So what happens?

GCP Health check -> checks HTTP/S load balancer -> FAILS because nginx server doesn't respond anything on port 80 on its public IP (or may be private ip) -> Because of that HTTP/S load balancer doesn't pass any traffic on port 80.

When accessing the nginx server directly to its IP http://public_ip, it doesn't work at all.

My question is. How can we make the nginx server to respond on its IP while still maintaining multiple domains server blocks?
or how can we make that health check pass?

Comment: If you configured a Network Load Balancer for port 443 and an HTTP(S) Load Balancer for port 80, then you have created at least two IP addresses.  That will not work unless both load balancers respond correctly on both ports. DNS servers do not recognize TCP port based queries. In essence Route 53 will round robin both addresses to clients (unless you configured Route 53 differently).

Comment: In GCP you can set the same public IP for both load balancers (network LB and HTTP/S lb).

Comment: It doesn't work on port 80 because the nginx load balancer server doesn't respond to health checks. it gives "empty response". Because of that, GCP HTTP/S load balancer doesn't pass any traffic on port 80.

We don't know what config to do in nginx load balancer to respond on its public/private ip for health checks.

Comment: Why do you need two LB's ? One for layer4 and second for L7 (HTTPS) ? Is there some special feature that requires also L4 being balanced ??

Comment: In order to pass traffic to port 80, I need HTTP/S load balancer.
In order to pass traffic to port 443, I need Network load balancer.

You can't do it with only one load balancer.

Comment: So you want your webserver to handle SSL instead of load balancer - right ? Have you tried to load balance traffic po port 80 too ? Maybe you tried setting up just one L4 LB for both ports ? Is that just one machine or a group of machines ?